# How to add javascript on wordpress nav menu

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, nav

On a wordpress mega menu, I want to show the product image on a different div when the mouse hovering a link. I work with the ubermenu plugin

I find a html+javascript code that work fine, but only when the ubermenu is implant by adding a shortcode on a page (exemple here : https://defil-communication.com/test-accueil/). The second menu work fine but the main menu don't.

Here is the code I added :

To all the product link

```
  <a href="https://my-product/" onmouseover="document.getElementById('image').src = 'my-image-1.jpg'">Beach Flag Crest</a>
```

To the div appears on fith column

```
 <img id="image" src="https://my-image-2.jpg" alt="image0" />
```

Do I have to declare the javascript somewhere ?

Thanks four your help

Comment: Hi, do you have knowledge in jQuery? you can do that with jQuery.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm not very comfortable for now with jQuery. Could you help me to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

[How to affect other elements when a div is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Javascript or jQuery is not required. Just access to the css file.
You can create a div and hide it. When on hover it can unhide.

Hope this helps.